# How to drop a database with "-" on its name in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax-error, ddl

I am trying to drop my databases that are named "login-system" and "test-application" in PHPMyAdmin, but it's giving me an error on the "-" it says "Unexpected token. (near -)".

Comment: Please can you show the exact code you are trying to run? It may be that you need to escape or quote characters

Comment: drop database test-application;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can escape object names in MySQL using the backtick character:

```sql
DROP DATABASE `login-system`
-- Here ------^------------^
```

Comment: @kramsuilujx if this answer helpt you out consider accepting it as the solution -> https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work